# html tags in CI controller

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Is it okay to have some html tags in codeigniter controller. Sometimes i found it difficult to decide that should i move logic into view or html into controller.

Suppose i want to show a textarea for only profile owner and administrator this can be done by two way(as far as i know).

1. Putting more php in view like

`if($this->session->username() == $user || $this->session->username() == $administrator){
echo '<textarea></textarea>';
}`

1. Putting html tags in controller like

> $data['textarea'] = "";    if($this->session->username() == $user || 
>   $this->session->username() == $administrator){
>
> $data['textarea'] = 'html textarea tages goes here';
>
> }
>
> $this->load->view('example', $data);

There are some other many cases where i found it almost impossible or v difficult to have separate html tags from controller like here i want to show menu with submenu also so we have to run two foreach loop one for main menu and the second one for submenu which only run if main menu has submenu.

Answer (score 0):

Use controllers to communicate with models, fetch results and prepare them to be easily handled in views. In other words, if you think of an operation which main goal is to display data, this operation - imo - should be done in a view. About the two options you showed, I would go with 1. I think it covers the idea of keeping logic and presentation separated better.

Answer (score 0):

Basic simple conditional and loops are ok to be in a view, but a controller shouldn't have html code. About your first option, maybe you should:

Controller:

```
$data['is_admin'] = ($this->session->username() == $user || 
                    $this->session->username() == $administrator);

$this->load->view('example', $data');
```

View:

```
<html>
...
<?php if ($is_admin): ?>
   <textarea></textarea>
<?php endif; ?>
...
</html>
```

Yes it is redundant code, you could put this conditional to view, though you would be accessing session value, which should be done by controller because it is the 'logic'. Conditionals are logical as well, but can you see how controller related is getting a value from CI_Session class?